# Limiting route access with a one time key

Tags: angularjs

I'm using this method on the login controller to return a user object

```
.controller('loginController', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.login = function (user) {
        var credentials = { Email: user.email, Password: user.password }
        $http.post('api/Login/Validate', credentials)
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.user = data;
                $location.path("/index");
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.user = null;
            });
        };
});
```

In the Chrome console I get the following object back:

```
Object {Admin: false Email: "email@email.com" Id: 12 OneTimeKey: "random string here"}
```

When the method tries to navigate to 'index', it uses the following route:

```
.when('/index', {
            templateUrl: '/Client/Views/index.html',
            controller: 'dashController',
            resolve: {
                oneTimeKey: function ($http) {
                    return $http.post('api/Login/VerifyOneTimeKey?oneTimeKey=' + OneTimeKey);
                }
            }
        })
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: OneTimeKey is not defined
at $routeProvider.when.when.when.resolve.oneTimeKey
```

I'm assuming I'm getting this error because the resolve can't grab the OneTimeKey variable at its current scope, but I could be wrong. Not sure how to solve this from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [resolve](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) option you can pass into `when()`. There is a good video on eggHead.io on it: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-resolve

Basically you could do something like this to check the server when a route is loading and conditionally prevent it from loading.

```
.when('/index', {
    templateUrl: '/Client/Views/index.html',
    controller: 'mainController',
    resolve: {
        oneTimeKey: function($http) {
            //The route will only be loaded if this promise resolves.
            return $http.get('api/oneTimeKey');
        }
    }
})
```

If you are loading the token in your controller then you will have to store it in a service so it can be accessed from the resolve. e.g.:

```
app = angular.module('myApp');

var UserSession = function() {

}

UserSession.prototype.initialize = function(session) {
    this.session = session;
}

app.service('userSession', UserSession);


app.controller('loginController', function ($scope, $http, $location, userSession) {
    $scope.login = function (user) {
        var credentials = { Email: user.email, Password: user.password }
        $http.post('api/Login/Validate', credentials)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.user = data;
                userSession.initialize(data);
                $location.path("/index");
        }).error(function (data) {
            //...
        });
    };
});

...

.when('/index', {
    templateUrl: '/Client/Views/index.html',
    controller: 'dashController',
    resolve: {
        oneTimeKey: function ($http, userSession) {
            return $http.post('api/Login/VerifyOneTimeKey?oneTimeKey=' + userSession.session.OneTimeKey);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I edited my question up to the point where I'm stuck at implementing your answer. I wonder if you could shed some further light. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Rex_C I edited my answer to show how to access the one time token from your resolve function